# How do I place a background image wider than the scene using SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

### What I need

I would like to know how to place a **SKSpriteNode** as a background image with a **SKTexture** of *3,240 by 1,920 pixels* on a **SKScene** while I keep it's aspect ratio using **SpriteKit** on **Swift 3**.

### Why I need it

The idea behind this is to have an image wider than the scene to achieve a parallax effect when the player moves.

### What I've tried

The following code place the image but shrink it to fit the scene breaking its aspect ratio horizontally:

```
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Background")

let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

if let view = self.view {

    background.size = view.bounds.size

}

background.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero

addChild(background)
```

[Scene screenshot with its width ratio broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqnsy.png)

The following code variant place the image but squish it also breaking its aspect ratio in this case only vertically:

```
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Background")

let background = SKSpriteNode(texture: texture)

if let view = self.view {

    background.size.height = view.bounds.size.height

}

background.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero

addChild(background)
```

[Scene screenshot with its height ratio broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ5i9.png)

If I leave the `background.size` property unset no image appears on the scene.

If I try the same code with a **SKTexture** of *1,080 by 1,920 pixels* it works fine.

Also, the scene `scaleMode` property is set with following line of code:

```
gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
```

### Thanks

Any kind of help will be very much appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time.

Cheers,
Federico.